# Is it possible to have a TextView without a Keyboard?

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

For the particular application I am developing the built in keyboards are useless for me (I need to support 0-9 and X, del and nothing else).  I also am after a UI with large buttons to make it easier to hit the keys.

It is easy enough to come up with a UI with the buttons, but I cannot figure how to make it so that the keyboard doesn't show up at all when the user select the TextView (I'd like them to never see it at all).

I do want the TextView feature of being able to select where the cursor is, otherwise I would punt and use a label.

Is this the wrong way all together and I should do it some other way?  If not is there a way to hide the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Make the TextVeiw uneditable and the keyboard won't come up

Comment: but then I won't have the ability to move the cursor withing the edit field.  I'd rather not have to delete 10 characters because the first one was wrong (and I cannot do validation until everything is entered)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  A textview without a keyboard is called a "label".  (And that won't help you with the insertion point, but them's the breaks.)

Comment: Since a label doesn't allow for cursor movement they are not the same.

Comment: I'm well aware of this.  Unfortunately for you, the cursor and the keyboard are a package deal; there's no known method to get one without the other, short if implementing an insertion point yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIView* emptyView = [ [ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero ];
textView.inputView = emptyView; // this will show emptyView (=nothing) instead of keyboard
[ emptyView release ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes We can Do that. Done by disable the User Interaction.
In your xib userinteraction is enabled like
[image]

you have to disable the user interaction like
[image]

If you created programmatically means, you have to write below code in viewDidLoad method like,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITextView *txtvew = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 150, 150, 300)];
    txtvew.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

}
```